# Can cartographer publish odom?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, ros-melodic, cartographer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to have the cartographer publish the odom topic in localization-only mode? I'm quite happy with the 2D localization results it provides, compared to other ROS methods using my very noisy IMU and slipping encoders, but I don't get the odom from it, despite `provide_odom_frame` set to true. Is it even supposed to work?

Thank you!
Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328830/can-cartographer-publish-odom?/) by [AlexM](https://answers.ros.org/users/41877/alexm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution/workaround: added a tf -> odom mapping node as suggested by @koby here: https://answers.ros.org/question/319521/why-cartographers-odom-from-tf-contains-much-noise/. Seems to work well.

---

Originally posted by [AlexM](https://answers.ros.org/users/41877/alexm/) with karma: 51 on 2019-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0